# Can't install gems on Windows 7 64

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, installation, windows-7-x64

No laughing now...
I say this because there are a lot people who have already asked, not necessarily for the sass gem but for other gems. Answers almost always deflect the asker into building a virtualbox linux environment.
Okay, I've already got that, but I'd like to use the windows environment for personal reasons. 
I followed Sass's own directions:
http://sass-lang.com/install

Ruby is supposed to be working in Windows 7, so I'd be grateful for answers that actually allow me to install gems in the windows environment. It's not a firewall issue. I turned off the firewall temporarily to check.

I've installed Ruby using the download at rubyinstaller.org.
I'm trying to install the sass gem. Gem will not install any gems, so it's not sass-specific.
It looks like the problem is related to https.
I'd be grateful if someone could tell me how to make this work.

```
PS C:\Users\Chris> ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]

PS C:\Users\Chris> gem -v
2.1.5

PS C:\Users\Chris> gem install sass
gem : ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
At line:1 char:1
+ gem install sass
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR:  Could n...), here is why::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server 
certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

PS C:\Users\Chris>
```

Comment: The error message in what you posted seems to imply that the problem is with your ability to verify a certificate coming from rubygems.org. I think that's what you'll need to track down.

Comment: Coenwulf, Thanks for your reply. That's exactly right. On a hunch, I downgraded from Ruby 2.0.0-p353 to 1.9.3-p484. Gems install correctly now. There is obviously a problem with the latest version of Ruby Installer that doesn't work on all versions of Win7 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading this on [RubyGems Github](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/665) that the problem might be with the installer I realized the problem might be with the installer. First I uninstalled the flawed version (Ruby 2.0.0-p353) and then installed 1.9.3-p484. Gem installs now run flawlessly, though not the latest preferred version.

Comment: FWIW, I've tried all Ruby version 2.x and none allow me to install Sass. I downloaded version 1.9.3-p551 and was able to install Sass as usual. For reference here's the link to Ruby's download page for Windows: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

As for me I closed the current prompt and opened a new command prompt window after installing DevKit then it was working fine.

check below full series of installation of ruby and ruby on rails on windows 7

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eFwV8lRu1w
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-YikrZqfbY
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0X7SUfF928
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy5x8aGKrrw